# Unable to import com.mongodb.MongoCredential in Eclipse mars

Tags: java, eclipse, mongodb

I am trying to make java MongoDB app, using jdk 1.8 and mongodb-driver-3.7.0-rc0, eclipse mars. I have added the mongodb-driver in referenced libraries. Eclipse allows me to import `com.mongodb.MongoClient`, and  `com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase`. But when I try to import `com.mongodb.MongoCredential`, it says:

```
The import com.mongodb.MongoCredential cannot be resolved
```

Any idea whats missing or wrong here?

Comment: Does an added JAR contain the file `com/mongodb/MongoCredential.class`?

Comment: No,it does'nt. I tried replacing mongodb-driver-3.7.0 with mongodb-driver-3.5.0. That version also don't have MongoCredential class.

Comment: [`mongo-java-driver-3.7.0-rc0.jar`](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.7.0-rc0/mongo-java-driver-3.7.0-rc0.jar) contains `com/mongodb/MongoCredential.class`. See https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.7.0-rc0

Comment: jar file on your provided link contains MongoCredential class. I was downloading drivers from [link](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver/3.7.0-rc0/) .Its absurd that there was no MongoCredential class in any driver. Thank you for the link @howlger

Answer (score 1):

It looks you only added [`mongodb-driver-3.7.0-rc0.jar`](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver/3.7.0-rc0/mongodb-driver-3.7.0-rc0.jar) that [combines mongodb-driver-sync and the legacy driver](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongodb-driver/3.7.0-rc0), but which does not contain `com.mongodb.MongoCredential`.

You can either:

- add **[`mongodb-driver-core-3.7.0-rc0.jar`](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver-core/3.7.0-rc0/mongodb-driver-core-3.7.0-rc0.jar) in addition** or
- add [**`mongo-java-driver-3.7.0-rc0.jar`**](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.7.0-rc0/mongo-java-driver-3.7.0-rc0.jar) ([containing the legacy driver, the mongodb-driver, mongodb-driver-core, and bson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.7.0-rc0)) **instead**.